# Django models - using two foreign keys values

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm pretty new in django so my question might be basic but still it would be great if you could help sicne I don't really know how to even look at this problem besides simplest method.
I have model like this:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And now I would like to pull all roles for the given project:

```
current_project = Project.objects.get(slug=slug_name)
```

and on the template display all roles as rows with job name (from Job model) and user name (from User model) in loop like this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>{{job.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
{% for role in current_project.role_set.all %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ role.job.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ role.user.username }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

> Is there way to do it in model or in view instead (not using another variable), like prefetch_related? Because the method in template generates multiple duplicate sql queries.

IIRC you can apply `prefetch_related` and `select_related` on the `Project` queryset in your view, ie

```
qs = Project.objects.prefetch_related(....).select_related(...)
current_project = qs.get(pk=...)
```

but this is from memory and I don't have time to double-check this right now...

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there way to do it in model or in view instead (not using another variable), like prefetch_related? Because the method in template generates multiple duplicate sql queries.